# Union of Integer, AbstractVector{Integer}, and String

Tags: julia

I have a function in which the user passes an argument to select which columns of a matrix should be processed as in the minimalistic example below:

```
function foo{P<:Real, T<:Integer}(;x::AbstractMatrix{P}=zeros(3, 10),    colN::Union(T, AbstractVector{T})=1)
   x[:,colN] = x[:,colN]+1
    return x
end
```

I want to have a way for the user to specify that all columns should be processed, in the end I changed the function so that this would be the default behavior:

```
function foo{P<:Real, T<:Integer}(;x::AbstractMatrix{P}=zeros(3, 10), colN::Union(T, AbstractVector{T})=[1:size(x)[2]])
    x[:,colN] = x[:,colN]+1
    return x
end
```

originally, however, I wanted to allow the `colN` argument to take a `String`, so that the user could pass it the value "all" to mean that all columns should be processed, but the following doesn't work as I expected:

```
 function foo{P<:Real, T<:Integer}(;x::AbstractMatrix{P}=zeros(3, 10), colN::Union(T, AbstractVector{T}, String)="all")
    if colN == "all"
        colN = [1:size(x)[2]]
    end
    x[:,colN] = x[:,colN]+1
    return x
end
```

calling this last version of the function gives:

```
foo(colN="all")
ERROR: `__foo#8__` has no method matching __foo#8__(::Array{Float64,2}, ::ASCIIString)
```

why such an union between an Integer, a vector of integers, and a string doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Julia can't deduce the type `T` when you pass a string, and is thus not able to resolve which method to call.

Consider the following two functions, `f` and `g`:

```
function f{T<:Integer}(x::Union(T,String)) 
    x 
end

function g{T<:Integer}(y::T, x::Union(T,String))
    x
end
```

In this case, you will observe the following behavior:

- `f(1)` is `1` because the value of `T` can be deduced
- `f("hello")` gives an error because the value of `T` is unknown
- `g(1, "hello")` is `"hello"` because the value of `T` can be deduced

That being said, I think that it would be more idiomatic Julia to use [multiple dispatch](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/methods/) instead of `Union` types to achieve what you want to do.

**Update.** Seeing as your `colN` is either a string or a list of indexes,  I believe you would be fine with `T = Int` (or `Int64` if you want to address a lot of memory). Compare the following function `h` to `f` and `g` above:

```
function h(x::Union(Int,String)) 
    x 
end
```

In this case, both `h(1)` and `h("hello")` work as expected (and e.g. `h(1.0)` raises an error).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I agree with the suggestion of using multiple dispatch, but then the argument `colN` cannot be (as far as I understand) a keyword argument, which I'd prefer because the actual function I want to write has a large number of arguments.

Comment: If you absolutely must use the name `colN` for something that can be a string, an integer or an array of integers, how about just not specifying `T` and the type of `colN`?

Comment: yes, that's an option, but then I should make sure inside the function that the user doesn't pass something else than an integer, a vector of integers or a string as the `colN` value, and throw a useful error message if s/he does

Comment: How about using `Int64` instead of `T` (just `Int` if you want to use platform native integers)? That way, you can probably stick with your `Union`, and end up simplifying your function as well.

Comment: regarding the update, `h(x::Union(Int,String))` won't work for an array of integers, only for a single index

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass a string in this function to indicate handling all columns.
Also, it looks like the matrix should be passed in as a positional argument,
instead of a keyword argument.
so that Julia can specialize on it.
There are many ways to handle this more efficiently in Julia.

```
function foo{P<:Real, T<:Integer}(x::AbstractMatrix{P}, colN::Union(T, AbstractVector{T}))
    x[:,colN] += 1
    return x
end
function foo{P<:Real}(x::AbstractMatrix{P})
    x[:,[1:size(x)[2]]] += 1
    return x
end
```

so `foo(zeros(10,3))` will give you:

```
3x10 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

and `foo(zeros(3,10),5)` will give you:

```
3x10 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. As I just said in the comment to @vindvaki answer I'd prefer `colN` to be a keyword argument. The example function I showed in the question is minimalistic, the actual function has many arguments and for that reason I prefer using keyword arguments.

Comment: Ok, but you could still simply use the absence of a colN keyword argument to mean "all", have it default to `nothing` instead of having to compare a string, or default to `0`, and treat `0` as a special value indicating "all".

Comment: the last solution is viable, but I'd like the function calls to be easily and immediately readable by a user, hence I prefer something like "all", instead of something arbitrary like "0" to mean process all columns. Of course this is a matter of subjective preference. Regarding the other solution, please could you give a working example? if I try changing `colN` to default to `nothing` `colN::Union(T, AbstractVector{T})=nothing` and then call the function without passing the argument  I get `ERROR: `__foo#1__` has no method matching __foo#1__(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Nothing)`.